# SVG - scaling issues with images

Tags: image, google-chrome, svg

Scaling a parent DIV containing an SVG that has image over a colored rect shows hairline edges from the underlying rect.

```
<div style='transform: scale(0.79454)'>
    <svg width="1280" height="720">
      <rect fill="yellow" width="1280" height="720"/>
      <image width="1280" height="720" transform='matrix(1.4,0,0,1.4,-200,-150)' xlink:href="https://storage.googleapis.com/firebase-beautifulslides.appspot.com/test/dawid-zawila-279995.jpg"/>
    </svg>
</div>
```

In the screenshot below, there is a yellow box beneath the image. Both are the same size but you can see the yellow box "bleed" out from the edges a bit (you may to view the full image or the fiddle below to see it clearly).

[image]
This artifact happens whether or not I transform the image node and also appears when I try scaling the SVG using a viewBox instead of the parent div. It's somewhat better in Safari than in Chrome but it does still happen in certain cases.

Here's a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/e17ea4j5/

Is there any fix to this?

Comment: Sure there is, remove the rect.

Comment: Thanks. Let's assume i'm not an idiot and this is a simplified example just to illustrate the issue.

Comment: there's no other answer to your question that's going to work except in limited ways as Paul's explained in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

What you seeing is the result of anti-aliasing. The semi-transparent pixels at the edges of the yellow rectangle are visible through the semi-transparent pixels at the edges of the image.

There isn't really any elegant solution to eliminate those issues. Especially when when you are scaling by fractions (eg. 1.4 and 0.79454).

You are left with somewhat hacky solutions like putting a black stroke around your rectangle.

```
<rect fill="yellow" width="1280" height="720" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
```

```css
body{
      background: black;
      margin: 0;
    }
```

```html
<body>
  <div style='transform: scale(0.79454)'>
    <svg width="1280" height="720">
      <rect fill="yellow" width="1280" height="720" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
      <image width="1280" height="720" transform='matrix(1.4,0,0,1.4,-200,-150)' xlink:href="https://storage.googleapis.com/firebase-beautifulslides.appspot.com/test/dawid-zawila-279995.jpg"/>
    </svg>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks, unfortunately that's not a viable solution in my case. I'm trying to solve for a more general authoring tool where an image can be arbitrarily positioned above a shape like the rect. It's not necessary for the image to completely mask the underlying shape like in my example - it may only be positioned along one edge and i don't want to mandate that the underlying rect has a stroke because portions of it may be intentionally visible.

Comment: The other option is to make sure that the rectangle and image are aligned to pixel boundaries exactly. That will at least solve the problem if the SVG is viewed at 1:1 (or multiples thereof).

Comment: The solution i came up with was the scale the rect slightly so it no longer bleeds through.
`style='transform: scale(0.999); transform-origin: 50% 50%'`

Comment: Be careful. `transform-origin: 50% 50%` works differently in SVG than in HTML. The 50% refers to the centre of the viewport of the SVG, not the centre of the object.  Also the percentage behaviour is correct in FF, but broken in Chrome